# could someone explain me why there should be a for loop in this code

Tags: python

I am learning python from a book (python crash course by Eric Matthes)
but i find this code imposible for me to understand.

```
def build_profile(first, last, **user_info):
         """Build a dictionary containing everything we know about a user."""
   profile = {}
   profile['first_name'] = first
   profile['last_name'] = last
   for key, value in user_info.items():
      profile[key] = value
   return profile
user_profile = build_profile('albert', 'einstein',
                  location='princeton',
                   field='physics')
print(user_profile)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this GeeksforGeeks article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/) for more details. In short, `**user_info` is a `dict` that contains  any additional named arguments you pass as key-value pairs. So in order to include it in the `profile` dict, we loop over its `items()`.

For example, if I call `build_profile('Steve', 'William', age=24)`, you would see that `user_info` would be `{'age': 24}`.

In the example you've included, it would be `{'location':'princeton', 'field':'physics'}`.

Comment: That line assigns value `value` to the key `key` in the `profile` dict. If `key` was not in the dict before, it is added. And if `key` was already there in the dict, it would have updated the value.